# Understanding Paypal Recurring IPN Array

Tags: arrays, authentication, paypal, subscription

Hi it has been awhile since i have worked with subscriptions but i could swear at one time i got the same kind of post values list doing print_r that i did with the onetime payment.

That is not the case so im sort of lost here.   When i do print_r on the $_POST value for my normal one time payment i get a whole list if elements in the array for which i can then save and process the payment.

But with subscription when i do the print_r on the $_REQUEST value all i get is this (using sandbox)

```
Array
(
    [auth] => A43hQ0tI4UbftdxovhXIt2bRwBVYD49ni3J-RNum5ivYYzJFLD-lyFEaE5FxDTPQBpUwNAChZ9UseiB5gkdgqhg
    [form_charset] => UTF-8
    [PHPSESSID] => b3689368f4deaa4099fe1b42421ea4ba
)
```

I am getting an error that i dont have a payment id number that i passed in the form, well no wonder its bombing because its not in the array.   Or do i need to decode the auth?

I had heard at one time they were going to limit the ipn array to a more secure array so does that mean that instead of looking for VERIFIED i just look for auth now.

Im just lost what to do with this, can you point me in the right direction here thanks.  I have my notify file written for a list of elements in the array, not for that little bit of data so im not sure what im suppose to do with that array lol...

For some reason i seem to remember something about testing subscriptions in sandbox only gives back the secured array not the normal array but that live process will give normal array.  Can anyone confirm this..

Comment: When you mentioned "payment ID number" are you referring to a transaction ID? You wouldn't get one in the first IPN post you get with a Subscription. The first IPN post you get is the subscription or recurring payment sign up which does not include a transaction ID. 
A transaction ID is provided in an IPN post later on when the actual payment occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paypal IPN for subscriptions sends more than one IPN response.  You must listen for the one where the 'txn_type' variable is 'subscr_payment' if its a new subscription, then 'recurring_payment' for subsequent payments.  You also need to listen for things like 'subscr_failed', 'subscr_cancel', 'subscr_eot' etc.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/

Comment: Sorry i thought i had notify by email on reply checked but  didnt get anything, sorry took so long..   They must have changed that in the last year or so because back before when they had the old  X support site i did one just like i have this one set up and it worked flawlessly.  So they must have not only changed their support structure but also the recurring payment IPN requirments. So i guess its back to square one on this and having to learn this new proceedure.  If i posted my IPN could you point in a good direction here.  Thanks.. I will check out that link you posted as well.

Comment: @patrick no i meant the userid that i sent in the form, it should come back to me in the post value so i can use that to finish the process.  Can you tell me this much, the array you see, is that the first or second or third IPN lol

Comment: well i am doing recurring not subscription, my bad i corrected the title.   and i give up trying to capture the txn type, its just not there and i have tried to capture it from beginning of sale to the sale final its just not there,   so i will just resort to doing the capture of the sessid that is in the array and completing the sale with that.  I must say that IMO paypal is going to pot, they keep messing things up, changing procedures and its driven me nuts, if its not support site change then its process or something always.  Im very unhappy with their management at the moment.